# Cannot push to an array from one Vue component to another. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've tried via Vuex using a Store (just for practice, also did not work). Since this is a small project I decided to opt out of using a central store and tried using an eventBus instead. I cannot pinpoint why nothing is pushing (or unshifting when using .unshift) to my empty array. No errors come out in the console. In using console.log within my function, I can see that the data is being logged and therefore received by the component but nothing pushes to the array.

Below is my code in order from component sending data to component receiving the data:

**Component Sending Data:**

```
<form class="form-group mt-4">
           <label for="blogTitle"><h4>Blog Title</h4></label>
           <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="blogTitle"
                v-model="blogTitle">
                <p>{{blogTitle}}</p>

           <label class="mt-3" for="blogBody"><h4>Blog Body</h4></label>
           <textarea 
                class="form-control no-resize" 
                name="entry" 
                id="blogBody" 
                cols="30" 
                rows="10"
                v-model="blogBody"></textarea>
                <p>{{blogBody}}</p>
            <button 
                class="btn btn-lg btn-dark mt-3"
                @click="postBlog">Post Blog</button>
       </form>
<script>
import {eventBus} from '../main'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            blogTitle: '',
            blogBody: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        postBlog() {
            eventBus.$emit('newBlogTitle', this.blogTitle);
            console.log(this.blogTitle);
        }
    },
    computed: {

    }
}
</script>
```

**Component Receiving Data:**

```
<div
        class="card ml-5 mr-5 mt-5"
        v-for="blog in blogs"
        :key="blog.id"
      >
        <div class="card-header alert-light text-info">
          <h3>{{ blog.blogTitle }}</h3>
          <small>
            <em>{{ getDate() }}</em>
          </small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>{{ blog.blogBody }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

<script>
import History from "./components/History";
import { eventBus } from "./main";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getDate() {
      const timeNow = new Date();
      return timeNow.toLocaleDateString();
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  components: {
    "blog-history": History
  },
  created() {
    let vm = this;
    eventBus.$on("newBlogTitle", data => {
      console.log(data);
      vm.blogs.push(data);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: you are emiting a string by `eventBus` and you are trying to iterate your `blogs` array as a object with properties that not have.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with example.  Not sure what you mean or how I can correct this.  Thanks